# Does uploading and downloading data from a private CloudKit database cost any money?

Tags: cloudkit

Do the data transfer costs from public to private or vice versa apply to simply using the private database to sync a file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's best posed to the sales/support team for the product in question, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but really a support question for Apple to answer (https://developer.apple.com/contact/)